# Remove "Google map" dashed border

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, border

i am not fluent in js and Html, i am trying to fix the map on our website that shows dashed border :

[image: Dashed border]

And the actual map look like this (on google map) :

[image: Actual map]

There is a political issue and google shows the map without border(dashed) to users inside Morocco and show the other map to the rest of the world users, we need to fix this as 90% of the target users on our website are from Morocco.

I have tried to fix it using this method :
https://daker.me/2017/08/fix-morocco-borders-on-google-maps-2017-version.html

But either the map vanish or no changes, the original map code :
http://pasted.co/46e7141b

I also tried to change the Google Map API domain from google .com to .co.ma

Please if there is any solution i would like to fix this as soon as i can, thank you in advance.

Comment: The code in that article works for me ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/153soq8j/1/)).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue you are having.

Comment: Hello, as i said i tested and didnt go as the tutorial maybe i did something wrong, can you please show me what i need to replace?

Comment: What does your code look like? All I see are pictures in your question.

Comment: Hi, here is the code http://pasted.co/46e7141b

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that you may not be able to change, but some of the styling of the map certainly can be altered. Google has a great tool here you can check out to investigate with:

https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Further details can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Comment: Hello, i checked, there is not option to blend only the dashed border with the map.

Answer (score 0):

Use `region=MA` query parameter in your API calls, see [localization docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization), 
and [demo](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/demos/localization/?region=MA&language=fr).